# Create Child record when Parent's Parent Updates

Tags: apex, trigger, class, insert

I have to be able to create a child record called "seats" when the parent of the parent object of "Seats" changes.

Teams -->Tables---> Seats

So when Team changes, I need to be able to create Seats for all the tables that are related to Teams.

I figured I should write a method that when Team changes, but how would I bring in the relationship of Tables to create the seats? I know I should query for it but I'm not sure how to get from setting my if statements to bringing in the query and then insert of seats.

```
   public static void makeNewSeats(Map<Id, Team> oldTeams, 
   list<Team__c> Teams){
   List<Seat__c> seatRecords = new list<Seat__c>();
   List<Table__c> tableRecords = "Query here???"();
    for(Team__c team : Teams){
        if(oldTeams.get(team.id).filled__c ==false && Team.filled__c == true){
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an approach, though I am guessing the relationship field API names.

```
public static void makeNewSeats(Map<Id, Team> oldTeams, 
   list<Team__c> Teams)
{
   List<Seat__c> seatRecords = new list<Seat__c>();
   Map<Id, Team__c> newMap = new Map<Id,Team__c>(Teams);

   //retrive table records based on team Ids
   Map<Id,Table__c> maptableRecords = new Map<Id,Table__c>([SELECT Id, Team__c FROM Table__c WHERE Team__c IN:newMap.keySet()]);

    for(Team__c team : Teams)
    {
        //check for which seat record to be created
        if(oldTeams.get(team.id).filled__c ==false && Team.filled__c == true)
        {
            //loop through table records
            for(Table__c tblObj:maptableRecords.values())
            {
                //compare the table record
                if(team.id == tblObj.Team__c)
                {
                    //here create Seat record.

                    Seat__c seatObj = new Seat__c();
                    seatObj.Table__c = tblObj.Id;

                    //assign relevant attributes of seat object.
                    seatRecords.add(seatObj);                   
                }               
            }//end of table for loop
        }
    }//end of for loop

    insert seatRecords;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks again!